# {SQLITE3} How can I force a query to not use a index on a given table?

Tags: sqlite, console

I am doing performance analysis over mondial database using sqlite3. One test case where I have to compare performance with and without using index (it should not use sqlite_autoindex as well).

I found this link :[How can I force a query to not use a index on a given table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016935/how-can-i-force-a-query-to-not-use-a-index-on-a-given-table) very useful but most of the answers refer to SQL SERVER. But I need it for SQLITE3. (I have tried PRAGMA options but no result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's buried in the syntax diagrams for [SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), but there is a way - Using `NOT INDEXED` with a table name in the `FROM` clause:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo(bar);
sqlite> CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON foo(bar);
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = ?;
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH TABLE foo USING COVERING INDEX foo_idx (bar=?)
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM foo NOT INDEXED WHERE bar = ?;
QUERY PLAN
`--SCAN TABLE foo
```

As you can see, the first query uses the index, and the second one doesn't.

[How to read EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! that's a quick and helpful answer. Phew!. Even after specifying NOT INDEXED SQLite optimizer still, use " autoindex", but that's not my focus as of now. I saw the documentation but found that this behavior of optimizer cannot be altered.